# How to reload variables from /etc/environment without re-logging in?

Tags: environment-variables

How to reload variables from `/etc/environment` without re-logging in?

`source /etc/environment` in bash works for program run through terminal, but running programs through shortcuts at GUI does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change the environment of a different process, as `gnome-session`, you can only change the environment of the current process and subsequent generated childs.

So, you are restricted to launch every process from the terminal where you *sourced* the new environment, to benefit from modifications.