# Syntax to declare the JAVA_HOME variable in /etc/environment?

Tags: java, configuration, environment-variables, environment, pkg-config

Where and how does the variable `JAVA_HOME` go?  What, [specifically](https://askubuntu.com/q/175514/45156), should the `environment` file contents be to correctly set `JAVA_HOME` alongside `PATH`?

current environment:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
thufir@doge:~$
```

Java settings:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for thufir: 
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME
thufir@doge:~$
```

without editing the user [profile](https://askubuntu.com/q/657436/45156).

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question:

[How to reload variables from /etc/environment without re-logging in?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49671/45156)

the answer would appear to be to use the `source` command, after declaring `JAVA_HOME` on a **second** line:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ source /etc/environment
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
thufir@doge:~$
```

However, it doesn't ***seem*** to work, insofar as the reason for setting `JAVA_HOME` complains:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ jars/apache-cxf-3.1.11/bin/wsdlvalidator
ERROR: Set JAVA_HOME to the path where the J2SE 6.0 (JDK6.0) is installed
thufir@doge:~$
```

While an answer, not sure that it's correct or complete.