# what is the value for JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, configuration, environment-variables, environment, pkg-config

What is the correct [value](https://askubuntu.com/q/908434/45156) for `JAVA_HOME`?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo nano /etc/environment 
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo locate openjdk
/etc/java-8-openjdk
/etc/java-8-openjdk/calendars.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/content-types.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/flavormap.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/images
/etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
/etc/java-8-openjdk/logging.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/management
/etc/java-8-openjdk/net.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/psfont.properties.ja
/etc/java-8-openjdk/psfontj2d.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security
/etc/java-8-openjdk/sound.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/swing.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/images/cursors
/etc/java-8-openjdk/images/cursors/cursors.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/management/jmxremote.access
/etc/java-8-openjdk/management/jmxremote.password
/etc/java-8-openjdk/management/management.properties
/etc/java-8-openjdk/management/snmp.acl
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/blacklisted.certs
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.policy
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security
/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/nss.cfg
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/THIRD_PARTY_README
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/docs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/extcheck
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/idlj
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java-rmi.cgi
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jcmd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdeps
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jhat
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jrunscript
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jsadebugd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstack
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/native2ascii
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/orbd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/policytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmic
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/schemagen
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/servertool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/tnameserv
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsimport
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/xjc
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/classfile_constants.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jawt.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jdwpTransport.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jvmti.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jvmticmlr.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jni_md.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jjs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/unpack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/calendars.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/classlist
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/content-types.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/currency.data
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/flavormap.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/hijrah-config-umalqura.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jar.binfmt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jvm.hprof.txt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/logging.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/meta-index
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/net.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/psfont.properties.ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/psfontj2d.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sound.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/swing.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/tzdb.dat
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg-default
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libattach.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_headless.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libdt_socket.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libhprof.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libicedtea-sound.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2gss.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pcsc.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pkcs11.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjaas_unix.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava_crw_demo.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjavajpeg.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjavalcms.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjdwp.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsdt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsound.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsoundalsa.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libmlib_image.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnpt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsaproc.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsctp.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsplashscreen.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libunpack.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/Xusage.txt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/classes.jsa
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/CIEXYZ.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/GRAY.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/LINEAR_RGB.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/PYCC.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/sRGB.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/cursors.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/invalid32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/management.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/snmp.acl
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/blacklisted.certs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.policy
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/nss.cfg
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jjs.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/policytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/jjs.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/policytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ct.sym
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/dt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ir.idl
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jconsole.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/orb.idl
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/sa-jdi.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/jli
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/extcheck.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/idlj.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jar.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jarsigner.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javac.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javadoc.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javah.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javap.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jcmd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jdb.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jdeps.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jhat.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jinfo.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jjs.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jmap.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jps.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jrunscript.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jsadebugd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jstack.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jstat.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jstatd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/native2ascii.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/policytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmic.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/schemagen.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/serialver.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/wsgen.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/wsimport.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/xjc.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/extcheck.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/idlj.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jar.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jarsigner.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javac.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javah.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javap.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jcmd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jdb.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jdeps.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jhat.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jinfo.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jjs.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jmap.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jps.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jrunscript.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jsadebugd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jstack.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jstat.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jstatd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/native2ascii.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/policytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/rmic.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/schemagen.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/serialver.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/wsgen.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/wsimport.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/xjc.1.gz
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-6-jre:openjdk-6-java.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-7-jre:openjdk-7-java.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-8-jre:openjdk-8-java.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-8-jre:openjdk-8-policytool.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/openjdk-6.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/openjdk-7.png
/usr/share/application-registry/openjdk-8-archive.applications
/usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-java.desktop
/usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-policytool.desktop
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jdk
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jdk-headless
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/JAVA_HOME
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/README.alternatives
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/copyright
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-hotspot-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-langtools-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/failed_tests-hotspot.tar.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/jtreg-summary-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/openjdk-8.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/openjdk-8.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/openjdk-8.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/openjdk-8.png
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openjdk-8-jre
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openjdk-8-jre-headless
/usr/share/mime-info/openjdk-8-archive.keys
/usr/share/mime-info/openjdk-8-archive.mime
/usr/share/pixmaps/openjdk-8.xpm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-8-jre:amd64.triggers
thufir@doge:~$
```

note that a sample at least *seems* to [install and run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43598502/262852) fine.  I was concerned about the JVM or JDK version number.  However, the Apache `WSDL2Java` conversion tool complains about the `JAVA_HOME` variable:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ jars/apache-cxf-3.1.11/bin/wsdlvalidator
ERROR: Set JAVA_HOME to the path where the J2SE 6.0 (JDK6.0) is installed
thufir@doge:~$
```

Perhaps there's another tool which utilizes the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, which could be used for testing?

Comment: Run `whereis java` one of the results should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java` or similar and it would be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle`

Comment: can't find or see a jdk, but updated the question.  I'm just using openjdk.  (netbeans was installed with umake.)

Comment: Run `sudo locate openjdk` and  you should see a list of files and the several with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` preceding. This is the `JAVA_HOME` Note the number for your may be `7,8` or `9`...

Comment: @George thanks.  perhaps there's another way to test `JAVA_HOME` itself?  Question updated.

Comment: The error message is asking for Java 6, which might actually mean it needs 6 instead of 8, and which would also mean that you should update the version of it so that it needs 8. Also, note that you should use `update-java-alternatives` instead of `update-alternatives`, so that you ensure you change over all Java executables (`jar`, `javap`, `javac`, `java`, etc).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex other demo's seem to run as:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598502/inspect-the-wsdl-for-an-example-from-wsdl2java  so I don't think so.  That's why I ran the sample.  On the same machine, same JVM and JDK.  But, I'll try `update-java-alternatives`.

Comment: This is your `$JAVA_HOME`:`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/` from your post you have to set it in `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 0):

as per George's comment:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ jars/apache-cxf-3.1.11/bin/wsdlvalidator https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL
WSIBP Validator found <{https://www.w3schools.com/xml/}TempConvertHttpPost> is NOT a SOAP binding
WSDLValidator Error : 
line 127 column 66 of https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'part' must appear on element 'mime:content'.

line 136 column 66 of https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'part' must appear on element 'mime:content'.

thufir@doge:~$
```

so, that's quite useful data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I set `$JAVA_HOME` in `~/.profile` this way:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac)))
```

I can change my java version, either by upgrade or through `update-alternatives`, and I don't have to remember to edit that variable.